# How to calculate the amount of aluminium that has been oxidised?

Tags: oxidation-state, metallurgy

1. I have a sample of pure aluminium (100%), 1 kg, stored in "normal condition"
2. After some time the weight of sample has increased by 1%.
3. I assume that aluminium has oxidized to $\ce{Al2O3}$

I know the weight before and after, and my question is: how to calculate how much aluminium has been oxidised?

Comment: First of all, welcome!  Starting point: from the molecular weights of Al and O, and the chemical formula of the oxidized product as you've given it, you can solve your problem.   Have you tried this?  Can you try it and show what you come up with?  Once you've made that effort others will be more motivated and better able to help answer your question (though you may answer it yourself if you try this!)

Comment: Yes, I have tried :), just wanted someone to confirm my calculation: As I understand the weight of 3 particles of O is almost same as 2 particles of Al - so simple calculation is: 1% of weight increase means 1% of oxidation - but I am not sure if this method of thinking is correct?

Comment: Absolutely.  Just post your calculation and I (and I'm sure others) will be happy to review and comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

- Initially, 1 kg of $\ce{Al}$ is present.
- After some time, oxidation increases the weight by 1%, or 10 g (e.g. 10 g of oxygen has been added).
- The atomic mass of oxygen is 16.0 g/mol.
- The molar ratio of $\ce{Al}$ to $\ce{O}$, from the molecular formula $\ce{Al2O3}$, is $\mathrm{\frac{2~mol~\ce{Al}}{3~mol~\ce{O}}}$.

$$\mathrm{\frac{10~g~\ce{O}}{16.0~g~O/mol~O}=0.625~mol~O}$$

$$\mathrm{\frac{2~mol~\ce{Al}}{3~mol~O}*0.625~mol~O=0.417~mol~\ce{Al}}$$

$$\mathrm{\frac{27.0~g~\ce{Al}}{mol~\ce{Al}}*0.417~mol~\ce{Al}=11~g~\ce{Al}}$$

Note that even though only a single significant figure is given for each of steps 1 and 2 of the problem, I assumed that they should read "1.0 kg" and "1.0%" rather than just "1 kg" and "1%" for the purposes of illustrating the above calculation. Thereby, 0.42 mol or 11 g of aluminum was oxidized to $\ce{Al2O3}$.